# Error while trying to process dimension in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas

I am getting the below error when I try to process my dimension in Analysis services from SQL Server Management Studio.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'AB_MATERIAL', Column: 'MAT_DESC', Value: 'SD DF44002R-N010 2.4L (Q)　'. The attribute is 'MAT_DESC_Attribute'.

I checked the dimension table AB_MATERIAL and am able to see the said missing value. However, whenever I browse the dimension is AS, I cannot see this value.

Can anyone help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the queries used in the data source view. Look for any flags or filters or joins on surrogate keys. If possible do a process clear and then process full database.

Comment: I find ssas errors frustrating to debug, but generally they mean exactly what they say.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13974559/4700939